How can I reduce temperature in a sunroom?
I have a room with 6 windows and a storm door. It was originally a "sun room" and now working from home, I have converted it into an office. I have 2 computers and 4 monitors so I know that adds to the heat in the room. It is routinely 5+ degrees warmer than the other rooms on our first floor.
We have blinds and blackout curtains on all windows and we keep them closed during the hot Eastern NC summer. We have a ceiling fan and an oscillating fan in the room as well. There are 2 vents connected to the main HVAC unit. The thermostat for that unit is in our den area and that area remains a comfortable 71 degrees F. We prefer not to go with a window unit AC or fan unit if possible.

Do the windows have any covering?  Awnings, drapes and/or sun film will reduce the rooms daytime temps.  Fans to mix that room's temp with the rest of the house will help some.

Is there any ductwork in the room linked to the main HVAC system?

Please see the [help]. This is a very open-ended question, and without a better description (or photos) it's hard to answer with specifics. Also, why can't you open an window? There are thermostat-controlled window fans to be found. Does that qualify as a "window unit"?

We have blinds and blackout curtains on all windows and we keep them closed during the hot Eastern NC summer. We have a ceiling fan and an oscillating fan in the room as well. There are 2 vents connected to the main HVAC unit. The thermostat for that unit is in our den area and that area remains a comfortable 71 degrees. We prefer not to go with a window unit ac or fan unit if possible.

Replace (some) windows with insulated wall.
Apply exterior shading if it's primarily a sun-impacted problem. Blocking the sun inside the room is still heating the room. Shadecloth or exterior blinds will block sun before it gets into the room to heat things up.
Improve flow or increase duct size to increase cooling capacity if the problem is the same at night as during the day. That might mean opening up this duct's dampers (if any) and closing dampers on other ducts slightly to change the balance on the system and cool this spot more.
